# Position: absolute a div over Flash

Tags: javascript, css, flash, internet-explorer, xhtml

Is it possible to `position: absolute` a `<div />` over a Flash banner without adding `wmode="transparent"` to the banner?

I have a lightbox that needs to appear above my ads but I can't directly modify the banners as they come from a third party.

**Edit**: The problem mainly occurs in IE where the Flash banner is shown above the lightbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not but you can just hide the banners when the lightbox is active.

Comment: This was my last-resort. Thanks for answering.   

For what it's worth, setting `visibility: hidden` on the Flash will stop your page jumping around like `display: none` would.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid no, if this was the case, we wold not have resorted to `wmode="transparent"`, but i hope there is a way around it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
wmode="opaque"
```

i think this will allow html div to be displayed over flash. It works for me many times but it behaves differently in different browsers.

Comment: I can't directly access the Flash code - it comes from a third party.

Comment: thanks for -1, you can modify  object or embed tag using DOM, isn't it?

Comment: You can't dynamically set wmode on object / embed tags. It's only read when the Flash is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could try the iFrame hack you would apply for IE to show an absolute div over a `select` element. It consists of dynamically (or even hard-coded, why not) creating an iFrame container that you position above the Flash (in your case) with the lightbox content inside it.

Someone correct me if they tested and does not apply here, but even if it does, I wouldn't recommend it unless it's a life or death situation.

Answer (score 0):

set the wmode="transparent" attrobute using javascript ??

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.flash_container embed').attr('wmode', 'transparent');  
});
```